# Can a unique position be inferred by measuring the magnetic field around a disk magnet?

Tags: magnetic-fields, simulations

I was wondering, assuming we have a disk magnet and we measure the magnetic flux density components at ANY point around the magnet (where it is still relevant), is it possible to conclude which point it was just by measuring $B_x$, $B_y$ and $B_z$? What I mean is, does every set of magnetic fiedl data map to a unique point in space? If yes, how can I explain/show that?

I have done a few simulations, simulating the three components for example on a plane 3mm under the magnet and on that plane, the found points are unique, but are they for every plane? Or would it be possible that a point at 3mm distance and at 5mm distance could yield to the same magnetic flux density (with different x,y coordinates of course)?

Comment: I think you are asking if a magnetic field can have the exact same direction and strength at two or more points?  The answer is yes. Take the case of an infinitely long solenoid. The field on the inside is homogeneous, which satisfies your condition in a whole volume. In practice we can't make an infinite magnet, but we can make magnets that approximate a homogeneous field to any desired precision.

Comment: This is exaclty my question but also if that is possible for a small disk magnet (D>H)

Comment: Yes, you could make a highly homogeneous field, at least in part of the volume, if you could magnetize the magnet properly. If you can't, then you could still shape the magnet to get the most homogeneous field possible. If I remember correctly, the field inside a magnetized sphere is homogeneous, so that's one example where, at least inside the magnet, one could not "navigate" by the field. Now, if you are interested in navigation, I would ask the exact opposite question: how would one arrange a number of magnets around a volume to get max. inhomogeneity?

Answer (score 1):

An *ideal* disk magnet surely has a line of symmetry through it's axis. Along this line, the magnetic field strength and direction are the same for points equidistant above and below the disk.

There is then another plane of symmetry going through the disk. At points in this plane that are equidistant from the axis of the magnet, the magnetic field will have the same strength and direction.

Below is a side view of roughly how I think your field should look - the details will be different but the symmetries will be similar.

In cylindrical coordinates the field has  $R$ and $z$ components, but not a $\phi$ component. When $z=0$, $B_R = 0$ and $B_z = f(R)$; when $R=0$, $B_R=0$ and $B_z=f(z^2)$.
This means you have a complete $\phi$ degeneracy (i.e. any azimuth) when $z=0$ and a bimodal $z$ degeneracy (i.e. above or below) when $R=0$.

[image: Field of a disk magnet]

Comment: is the direction the same above and below the magnet? Isn't it positive and negative? I am trying to think about this question in a "measuring"-way, not in a "in theory possible"-way :) Like a have the (axially magnetized) magnet in the room and I measure at a point around it (not inside it or at the surface) and the measurements are positive or negative depending on the quadrant one measures in.. shoulnd't the position then be unique?

Comment: @Kathiieee see the picture. When $R=0$ the field always points upwards.

Comment: my fault, so there is always a point above and below that are equal but if I would only consider data points below the magnet there is only one point per set since $B_x$ and $B_y$ switch sign? Sorry I am very confused at the moment... or let me rephrase, how would I need to restrict the area of measurement to get unique points?

Comment: @Kathiieee If you restrict yourself only to the half volume above or below the plane of the magnet and stay away from the disk plane, then the field components will be unique (for an ideal disk magnet).

Comment: thats what I was waiting for, so only above and below and no surface touching, I think I can live with that.. But how can I prove or properly explain that?